# How can I change the value of an object in an array in react redux when the action is called?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

This is the action that when it's called it gets an id so it can filter the object with the same id in reducer .

```
export const buyItem = (24) => {
    return {
        type: BUY_ITEM,
        payload: 24
    };
};
```

This is the array of products in reducer file

```
    products: [
        {
            id: 1,
            price: 4500000,
            number: 0,
            inCart: false
        },
        {
            id: 24,
            price: 7210000,
            number: 0,
            inCart: false
        },
        {
            id: 10,
            inCart: false,
            category: 'electronics',
            number: 0,
        }
]
```

This is the reducer action case that I filter the product filter then I try to update inCart and number value of it

```
    switch (action.type) {
        case BUY_ITEM:
            let item = state.products.filter((item) => {
                if (item.id === action.payload) {
                    return item;
                }
            });

            console.log(state.products);

            return {
                ...state,
                productsInCart: state.productsInCart + 1,
                cartPrice: state.cartPrice + item[0].price,
                products: [
                    ...state.products,
                    state.products.map((item) => {
                        if (item.id === action.payload) {
                            item.inCart = true;
                            item.number += 1;
                        }
                    })
                ]
            };
```

The problem is it's not doing it properly it actually changes the object values successfully but when console log happens after the action is done it shows me this :

```
21: {id: 19, nam, number: 0, …}
22: {id: 22,  number: 0, …}
23: {id: 23, n,…}
24: {id: 25, name: "Adidas کیف", pric دهید", number: 0, …}
25: (25) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
26: (26) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
27: (27) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
28: (28) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
29: (29) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, {…}, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,  undefined, undefined]
30: (30) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
31: (31) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, {…}, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

It basically adds multiple null arrays to the end of products array which is how I see is not what I want .
How can I properly update an object's value in an array when the action is called ?

Comment: You are using ```Array.filter``` in wrong way.

Comment: How can I use it properly ?

Comment: @DrewReese answer is correct

Comment: When you need to find one item you have to use ```Array.find``` nor ```Array.filter``` It will return an array not an object.

Comment: Well, OP *does* use `item[0]` later to set `cartPrice`, but in either case, array::filter *can* return an empty array like array::find can return undefined if nothing is "found", need to test the result exists before accessing it in order to prevent "undefined access ... of ... " errors.

Comment: Yes, it is. Because of that i said your answer is correct. and not need to make complex and makes two traverse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Products is copied (spread) back into itself, and then also a mapped products is nested into it (the undefined values come from not returning/mapping to new values). You can simply set the new products to *be* the mapped product array.

```
products: state.products.map((item) => {
    const newItem = { ...item }; // copy item
    if (item.id === action.payload) { // update if id matches
      newItem.inCart = true;
      newItem.number += 1;
    }
    return newItem; // return copied item
  })
```

Comment: As an addition to this answer, you're conceptually doing the same as the following short snippet `[1, 2, 3].map((item) => {})`, which returns an array of undefineds: `[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]`

Comment: no it is not, it is returning ```newItem``` either changed or not.